# What is the effect on speed and power when we connect three motors on a single shaft?

Tags: power, motor, torque, speed, rpm

Rolls Royce used three 750R (YASA) motors in their aircraft "Ionbird." All motors are mounted on the same propeller shaft.

- What is the effect on the overall speed and power of the motors?
- What changes would there be in the torque, RPM, etc.?

Comment: The equivalent torque is 3x higher, so the power is.

Comment: Look at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/531975/three-phase-motors-in-parallel-possible

Comment: Homework - Clearly cut-n-paste from a physics or other class.

Answer (score 1):

Because they are connected to the same shaft their speed has to be the same, but their torque adds up, therefore their power adds up.

It is like connecting batteries in parallel where the voltage must be the same but the current adds up.